# Newsbeuter - parse article before reading to get full article text

Tags: rss

There are a lot of rss feeds having very short description and they force you to open "read full article" or "read more" link on every article, since from that 1 or 2 sertences in description you cannot understand a lot.

So I was thinking. There is service like [Mercury](https://mercury.postlight.com) that lets you receive a full **clean** text of an article if you pass him an `url` of the full article, right? Maybe there is a functionality to use this service on every article in my feed, and when I want to read a selected article, instead of newsbeuter showing me the text in `description` tag of a feed, it will get the `url` tag (which is a link to full article), pass it to some script which sends this `url` to `mercury` for it to extract the article contents, and then displays me this parsed result.

Is is possible to implement this in newsbeuter? in result I want to be able to read the full article without leaving newsbeuter.

**PS:** since I do not have enough reputation here, please edit this post and add `newsbeuter` tag to it, and maybe some more that you think are relevant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Newsbeuter supports [filters](https://web.archive.org/web/20170611140731/http://www.newsbeuter.org:80/doc/newsbeuter.html#_scripts_and_filters_snownews_extensions)—little programs that transform the feed before it's consumed. In your case, such a filter would examine each item, get the "permalink" to the article, run it through Mercury service, and use the result as a "description" of the item. That's quite a lot of work, but the filter you get is universal, i.e. you'll be able to use it with any other feed (provided your feed parser supports all formats).